# python changing headers

Tags: python, http-headers

how do i change my headers and request so that i appear as firefox ...

like when request to some servers

```
import urllib
f = urllib.urlopen("rss feed")
```

they deny my request saying your client dosent have permission...

i get reply but the reply contains " your client dosent have permission"

so how do i get around this and get the data...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://vsbabu.org/mt/archives/2003/05/27/urllib2_setting_http_headers.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use good old `urllib` instead of newer, fancier `urllib2`, then as [urllib's docs](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib._urlopener) say, and I quote,

```
For example, applications may want to specify a different User-Agent header than URLopener defines. This can be accomplished with the following code:

import urllib

class AppURLopener(urllib.FancyURLopener):
    version = "App/1.7"

urllib._urlopener = AppURLopener()
```

Of course, you'll want a `version` (aka User-Agent header) suitable for whatever version of Firefox (or w/ever else;-) you want to pretend you are;-).